# Xamarin Forms ToolbarItems shown on the wrong page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Issue with the ToolbarItems.
So i start my application and in the constructor I check if somebody clicked on an element from the listview which is on my main page. If that happens, I'll start a new page. The error I have is that the toolbaritems from the mainpage are still displayed now.

Comment: Can you provide some demo code. please? Do you use `Navigation.PushAsync()` to show the new page? How are your `ToolbarItems` defined?

Comment: Hi i added the code which opens the page

Comment: At first I had the ToolbarItems defined in XAML but later I defined them in the c# code of the mainpage I thought this would maybe fix it but nope :)

Comment: So the `ToolbarItems` are only defined on the `MainPage`. When do you create them, in the constructor? And after the navigation to the `LoginPage` the `ToolbarItems` are still there?

Comment: Yes that's why I think this could be a xamarin bug

Comment: On which platform are you testing?

Comment: Currently I'm using Android

Answer (score 0):

Here this is the Method I use in the constructor :)

public void LoadLastPortal() {

```
        if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("LastPortal"))
        {

            String LastPortal = App.Current.Properties["LastPortal"].ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastPortal))
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage(App.Current.Properties["LastPortal"].ToString()));

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your issue, but in my sample app it works. See here the code for the `MainPage`:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem { Text = "test1" });
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem { Text = "test2" });
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem { Text = "test3" });
    }

    private void NavigateButtonOnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
    }
```

After I pressed the Button on the `MainPage` I'm navigating to the `SecondPage` and the three `ToolbarItems` aren't shown. Please provide some more information, so I'm able to help you.

Comment: Yes if I click a Button that opens a new Page it works fine but try to open a Page from the constructor like if a user just saves his setting and you open the app another time the method know that and just skips the login and opens automaticly the new Page than this bug occurs

Comment: I also tried to use this : ToolbarItems.Clear();
On the Appearing of the second Page but it does nothing

Comment: In this scenario you should first check if the user needs to be navigated to another page. And if this isn’t the case than you will add the ToolbarItems. I think this is some kind of race condition. He tries to add the ToolbarItems and than he navigates and than there is some kind of issue. Can you try this please?

Comment: Okay last week I just tested one test case but now I see there is another problem because if I click now on the "Navigation back button"  the buttons won't be displayed.